# Locals variables in the debug windows

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, f#, visual-studio-debugging

I'm unable to see local variable `result` within Locals windows of MS Visual Studio, all the other variables and their types display just fine.

Control is already at line 33 but I don't see effect of line 29 (refer to the image)

Code for line 28 and 29

```
let dataContractJsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof<List[]>)
let result = (dataContractJsonSerializer).ReadObject(memoryStream) :?> List[]
```

**Edit - as per request for more code**

```
[<DataContract>]
type List= {
    [<field: DataMemberAttribute(Name="href") >]
    Href: string
}
```

**service call**

```
let response = request.GetResponse() :?> HttpWebResponse
use reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
use memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reader.ReadToEnd()))
let result = (new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof<List[]>)).ReadObject(memoryStream) :?> List[]
```

[image]

Comment: What happens if you hover over result?

Comment: every other storage type shows a tooltip except `result`

Comment: This is because of optimizations. `result` doesn't exist in compiled code.

Comment: is it because it's a return result?

Comment: using breakpoint at the caller level and I can see it over there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: It looks like it's not appearing because of optimization.

Quote from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa309368(v=vs.71).aspx : "The effect of the optimization is to remove the code related to variable z, which is never used. Note also that the Locals window does not contain a node for the variable z."

```
private void InitializeComponent() {
...
  int j = 10, k = 20, z = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    z = j+k;
    btnNumbers[i].Size = new Size(30, 30);
    btnNumbers[i].Click += new System.EventHandler(btnNumbersClicked);
 }
...
```

If you could, please paste the complete code rather than just two lines.

That being said, this works for me. It's possible you left out `DataContracts` and `DataMember` from your class.

[image]

Comment: added some more, what do you think about the difference?

Comment: I had a casting applied, but you didn't have it either, secondly you are using c# and I'm using f#, so maybe it's compiler optimization as per @Fyodor Soikin

Comment: Yes that's correct. I just wanted to see all of your code before concluding that it was optimized. I've reflected my answer as well.  Check it out here:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa309368(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I've added the example as well in the answer